# What is the best practices for rigging a Cartoon Character

Tags: texturing, rigging, armature

I would ask you for best practices with cartoon character.

I have cartoon character, that have separated parts of body. Head, body, arms, foots. Can I use armature for manage poses?

Armature works with joined components, but in case I join the components, I loose the perfect texture mapping that I did for each part separately.

Should I join all the parts and create textures and mappings as the last step?

How to keep positions and transformations of two objects - in case they are unjoined and Im moving by one of them - head - by bone?

- I have eyes that must be - of course - parts of head. But bulbs and lashes must be in-depended - not joined - because they must be moveable.

[image: Screenshot]

The body texture was perfect before I joined the head and body because of armature.

Comment: You can simply parent several meshes to one armature and continue rigging just with several meshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't join the meshes, leave them separate.  The easiest way would be to modify the origins of your meshes so they rotate the way you want them to, instead of using armatures.

To do that, select your mesh, move the 3d cursor to the location you want your mesh to pivot from, and then select Object > Transform > origin to 3D cursor.  Now you need to parent your meshes to the body.  Select all of the appendages, and then select the body last.  Now press Ctrl + P and select object.  This will parent your arms and legs to the body.  You can now move them independently, but they will still follow the movement of the body.

If you wanted the antennas and eyes to move separately from the head, just parent the antennas to the head before you parent the head to the body.

[image]